# Scheduled task keeping application alive

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an application, made with javafx, which schedules a runnable to run every day, using `scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, initialDelay, 24*60*60*1000, TimeUnit.Milliseconds)`

Even though I cancel this task using `scheduledFuture.cancel(true)`, my application is kept alive, in the background, after the user has closed it.

I'm pretty sure this scheduling is the only thing keeping the application alive. If I don't schedule it, the application closes all right.

Comment: I havent used this myself just dug through api's. try calling shutdown on the scheduledExecutorService

Comment: Indeed, this worked =). Thanks! I had forgotten about the scheduledExcutorService itself, didn't think it would keep the app alive... Only cancelling the tasks is not enough, then.

Comment: It will need threads to manage the other tasks a quick read of the api and it occurred to me. I posted as an answer for ease of others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling [`shutdown()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) on the `scheduledExecutorService` allowed the program to shut down normally.

```
scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
```

According to the javadocs,

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed

Whereas calling [`cancel(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) just cancels the task, leaving the executor service alive, `shutdown()` kills the executor service as well, allowing the program to exit.